# Spark sql - How to concate string rows after grouping by particular column

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, dataset

I am writing an application in spark using java. I got into a problem where i have to concate string from different rows after grouping rows by particular column. Any help is appreciated !! Thanks.

**Input dataset**

[image]

**Expected output dataset**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collect_list` when you group by and then use `concat_ws` function to make the string from the list.

```
df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
|Errors                                |userid|associationtype|associationrank|associationvalue|sparkId|
+--------------------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
|Primary Key Constraint Violated       |3     |Brand5         |error          |Lee             |4      |
|Incorrect datatype in  associationrank|3     |Brand5         |error          |Lee             |4      |
+--------------------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+


df.groupBy("userid", "associationtype", "associationrank", "associationvalue", "sparkId")
  .agg(collect_list("Errors").as("Errors"))
  .withColumn("Errors", concat_ws(", ", col("Errors")))
  .show(false)

+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|userid|associationtype|associationrank|associationvalue|sparkId|Errors                                                                 |
+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|3     |Brand5         |error          |Lee             |4      |Primary Key Constraint Violated, Incorrect datatype in  associationrank|
+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> sdf
.groupBy("sparkid")
.agg(collect_set($"errors").as("error_list"),first(struct($"*")).as("data"))
.select($"data.*",concat_ws(",",$"error_list").as("errors_new"))
.show(false)
+-------------------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|errors                               |userid|associationtype|associationrank|associationvalue|sparkid|errors_new                                                           |
+-------------------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Incorrect datatype in associationrank|8     |brand3         |dd             |LeeNew          |7      |Incorrect datatype in associationrank                                |
|Incorrect datatype in associationrank|4     |brand4         |null           |Lee             |3      |Incorrect datatype in associationrank                                |
|Incorrect datatype in associationrank|1     |brand1         |iuy            |Lee             |0      |Incorrect datatype in associationrank                                |
|Primary Key Constraint Violated      |2     |brand1         |something      |Lee             |5      |Primary Key Constraint Violated,Incorrect datatype in associationrank|
|Primary Key Constraint Violated      |2     |brand2         |22             |Lee             |1      |Primary Key Constraint Violated                                      |
|Primary Key Constraint Violated      |3     |brand5         |error          |Lee             |4      |Primary Key Constraint Violated,Incorrect datatype in associationrank|
|Primary Key Constraint Violated      |3     |brand3         |40             |LeeNew          |2      |Primary Key Constraint Violated                                      |
+-------------------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```